# Update failure on SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition + Storing Generated Patterns = Computed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Working on a site using ADO.NET. Inserting a customer into a database, the same code and and model on my friend's laptop worked good but with mine, I got the `datetime2` to `datetime` out of range update exception on saving to the DB. The only difference we found was the version used for the server mine, 10.0.1600 and my friend 10.50.2500.

I can solve it by inserting into the code `datefield = DateTime.Now;` but I want to know what is happening exactly.

We are blaming it on the error. Also, when STORING A GENERATED PATTERN (e.g. a field is true by default or in this case the default time stamp by using `getDate()`, we write store generated pattern = COMPUTED in the model. On my friend this worked but on mine, this did not.

Can I confirm that the version is the problem? So that I can happily write in the code the defaults we should insert? Or do I have some other problem?

Thank you all

Comment: It would help if you could post some code.

Comment: SQL Server v10.0.* = SQL Server **2008**, v10.50.* = SQL Server **2008 R2** .... also : are you using Entity Framework or straight ADO.NET ??

Comment: @Aristos : I am not even inserting the date, the date should be inserted automatically when a record is added :)

Comment: @RickNZ
The DATA LAYER:

public int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            this._entities.Customers.AddObject(customer);
            return CommonMethods.Save();
        }

Then the following method is called:

public static int Save()
        {
            return _entities.SaveChanges();
        }

Where an Update exception occurs on this line!

Comment: I am a bit confused since my version of the server is r2 !All I know is that I am using a model which maps the database schema!

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

If you are using common culture, uiculture in your application then define the

```
culture="en-GB"
uiCulture="en-GB"
```

under globalization in the web.config

Or

Use Convert(date,getdate()) to get the current date of system which you need to insert the record.

Comment: Globalization did not make a difference :/

Comment: let me know your code used to insert the record in the database.

Comment: OK JUST SOLVED THE PROBLEM. it seemed that in my code, when I went to the properties of each field to change its generated pattern to COMPUTED, the XML file of the model was not changed. We used a tool to compare each others model. What to do: right click on the .edmx file in the solution explorer. OPEN WITH = XML TEXT EDITOR...add the following code near the fields which consist of a default value or binding in the sql server: StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed". this code should not be there before.